# Variable not defined after import script in Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to import a JavaScript file into my Vue application (inside the main.js) but the console says `Uncaught ReferenceError: CI is not defined`.

`CI` is a variable inside the Defines.js, a third party library that unfortunately I can't do any modification. See the code below:

`main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import './afw/Utils/Defines.js' // <<< this line!

console.log(CI) // <<< I got the error here!

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

As `Defines.js` is a private script with sensitive information I can't show you too much of this. However, here is a part of this script:

```
var CI = {};

...

if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = CI.Utils.Define;
}
```

What should I do to get it to work? If I move to a classical web application (import scripts with `<script/>`) it works, but I need to use VueJS 2.

**Update**

I'm also having the same trouble when I import another JavaScript that needs the variables inside the `Defines.js`:

```
import './afw/Utils/Defines'
import './afw/System/Core.js' // <<< Core.js needs a variable inside the Defines.js
```

Comment: Can you import it with `import Define from './afw/Utils/Defines.js'; console.log(Define.CI);` or `import { CI } from './afw/Utils/Defines.js'; console.log(CI);`?

Comment: None of those options works! I think that the last one `import { CI } from './afw/Utils/Defines.js' ` will only work if I have an `export` inside the JavaScript file but unfortunately, I can't change a line of code of this script.

Comment: Maybe `const CI = window.CI;` (if the Define.js script creates a global variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are exposing what is inside `CI.Utils.Define` and not `CI` itself. There is no way around this unless you export `CI` from inside `./afw/Utils/Defines.js`.

It works when you include it in a webpage via script because there is no notion of modules there and CI ends up being declared on the `window` object, but as you noticed this isn't the case when working with modules.

Comment: I was suspicious about that! In this case, I started using Vue as a common library ([installation guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html)) by including it using `script` tags in my html file.